Я пытаюсь создать функцию на Python, которая помогает реализовать и продолжить следующий числовой паттерн
Наткнулся на интересную задачку, у меня есть паттерн:
1
2 4
6 8 10
13 15 17 19

Мне нужно написать функцию, которая реализует и продолжает данный паттерн. Только необходимо это сделать именно используя тот факт, что начиная со 2 строки, следующая строка = предыдущая + 3 и так далее.
Мой вариант использования данной особенности:
def print_pattern(row):
    number = 1
    for i in range(1, row + 1):
        number += 1 + (n-1)*3
        for j in range(n):
            print(number + 2 * i, end=' ')
        print()

print_pattern(4)


На данный момент вывод:
2 
6 8 
13 15 17 
23 25 27 29 

Задача в том, чтобы вывод был такой, что и в примере и работал с той же закономерностью дальше, но важный критерий не изменять саму идею моей закономерности:
Первая ступень: Начинаем с “1”.
Вторая ступень: Поднимаемся до “2”. Разница с прошлой ступенью - 1
Третья ступень: Поднимаемся до “6”. Разница с прошлой ступенью - 4
Четвертая ступень: Поднимаемся до “13”. Разница с прошлой ступенью - 7
Разница между первыми числами каждого ряда увеличивается с каждым шагом. 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19...  (см фото)

Это сейчас называется "математической моделью". Полчаса сидел и пытался понять, чего хотят, где тут хоть что-то не от фонаря взятое.

не особо осведомлен в терминах, если нужна какая-та дополнительная информация, задавайте,  попробую более ясно все изъяснить

Самое лучшее, что можно сделать для получения результата - написать задачу здесь КАК ЕСТЬ, буквально, просто скопировав условие из того учебника, не своими словами, без рисунков и интерпретаций. "Свой код", понятно, только для удовлетворения правил. Когда начинают "напевать Моцарта", пользуясь своими вокальными данными, впечатление от музыки, как сами понимаете, не очень. Пока что в условии задачи такое - напишите мне код для формирования последовательности, но это код должен быть мой. Так что писать??? Ваш код?


Задачка взята не из учебника, конкретные условия придуманы мной из возникшей по ходу ее решения проблемы 2) Я знаю, что последовательность можно реализовать иным способом, здесь конкретно вопрос стоит о том, чтобы решить ее используя тот факт, что первые числа отличаются друг от друга тем, что первое число предыдущей строки это следующая строка + 3, вот в чем заключается сама поставленная задача, если у вас получится не использовать мои наработки/код- да только лучше будет, я привел его просто для того, чтобы вам было проще. У меня не стоит задача решить эту задачу иным паттерном


@NowhereMan , нужно получить вывод
1
2 4
6 8 10
13 15 17 19
Паттерн я расписал может быть немного не понятно, но моя закономерность в том, что начиная со 2 строки, следующая строка = предыдущая + 3 и так далее, понимаю, объяснять не совсем мое, надеюсь вы уловили суть

@NowhereMan изменил вопрос, чтобы вам было проще, следом после вашего аргумента о том, что не соблюдаются условия было пояснение: шаг равен 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19... - вот моя закономерность, основываясь на которую необходимо решить это не хитрую задачку

это?

Классический вариант реализации с вложенными циклами:
def p1(row):
    d = 1
    n = 1
    for i in range (1, row + 1):
        for m in range(n, n + i * 2 - 1, 2):
            print(m, end = " ")
        print()
        n += d
        d += 3

Также можно сократить присваивания, избавиться от вложенного цикла и вывести последовательность внутри print:
def p2(row):
    d, n = 1, 1
    for i in range (row):
        print(*range(n, n + i * 2 + 1, 2), sep = " ")
        n, d = n + d, d + 3

Полностью однострочный вариант, с использованием "моржового" присваивания:
def p4(row): n, d = 1, 1; [(print(*range(n, n + 2 * i + 1, 2)), n := n + d, d := d + 3) for i in range(row)]


